# Cons of Static References to singleton "manager" objects?

Tags: java, oop, singleton

I am in the process of making a game in pure Java (in fair part as a learning experience, as I am quite new to programming) and I am finding that I am passing the same references constantly, namely "manager" type high-level singleton objects: World, PlayerManager, EnemyManager, TargetManager, ItemManager, etc.

Currently I only make static reference to my Final Constants/Utility method class, which contains things similar to java.lang.Math.

What I am thinking is that having static references to these objects will drastically decrease the amount of passing and this.boop = boop'ing I'll have to do, but something *feels* bad-practice about it and I'm not sure why.

- I don't have to worry about being thread-safe
- All of the objects I want to Statically reference are Singletons created at game start

What are the cons of doing something like this?

Edit:

In order to avoid using Static I could create a ReferenceManager object and just pass that around, but this seems needlessly obtuse.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Azar pros/cons are not good questions on programmers.SE...

Comment: Other than the difficulty of testing static objects, there are no cons if you don't need thread safety.

Comment: Why in Goku's sake would you need a singleton manager? SIngletons are singletons, they manage themselves (and that's why I'm not a fan of this pattern).

Comment: Thank you Harvey. @Henrique I know singletons manage themselves, but I still need to reference them elsewhere in my program, and quite often. Do you have a preferred alternative to accomplish this other than simply passing the references a bunch?

Comment: Using singleton this way you're doing is probably an anti-pattern. Furthermore, why you can't just reference them as `SomeSingleton::getInstance()` throughout your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pro is obviously performance: if you can access the instance you need in fewer steps then you can begin to use it more quickly. Also, if you initialize these "singletons" at your app startup, there's no hit when other modules are trying to access, so your singletons don't even need the `if null then instantiate` logic typical in `getInstance()` implementations.

One con is in high coupling. Now your modules all know specifically about this instance and how to access it. That makes maintenance a bit more difficult as well as unit testing, mocking, etc., since your modules only know about *that* instance. Also, you can't make a second implementation of your `TargetManager` that is more efficient in one way or another and swap them out or select one for a different purpose (OO instance substitution) either at startup or dynamically.

Another con is with single-ness: now you can't have a second `World`. It might never come up, but if you make a server/client app, the server may track multiple `World` instances, and that becomes difficult to refactor. You could use something like `world1.get()` and `world2.get()` and just have two singletons, and now your modules need to know which to grab. This can greatly complicate things now that everything needs to know the criteria as well as the means of access whereas if you pass a reference (essentially just injection) it's less each module knows about its environment, which is again a coupling plus.

In some contexts, such as OSGI, there is some playing around with classloaders so singletons aren't really singletons in several cases.

I'm sure there are some other useful blog posts and such online deprecating the use of singleton for one situation or another.

All that aside, game programming is about cutting the right corners, so if you know you don't have to worry about any of those cases, then not passing references around through the layers of your code is a performance win, and direct access rather than some sort of registry lookup is another. In systems programming, the corners you cut today sometimes cut you tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer, and especially for your differentiation between game and system programming.